# Printing the amount of all numbers between 1 and the number. No errors and it doesnt work

Tags: c#

trying ti create a program that will observe a number and calculate the amount of all the numbers between 1 and the number that has been observed.
I've been asked to use a function to do so. No errors are showing up when i run the program, it observes the number and does nothing after that. There's the code:

```
using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
 namespace ConsoleApplication2
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            int i;
            int n=0;
            int a=0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            i = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            AmountOfNumbers(ref i,ref n,ref a);
            Console.Write(a);
        }
         static void AmountOfNumbers (ref int i,ref int n,ref int a)
            {
            while (n < i)
            {
                a += n;
            }
            }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks ahead.

Comment: You should use `return` rather than `ref` on all your parameters.

Comment: This was a fairly obvious problem and easy to diagnose, but in the future you should try stepping through your program and using watch or the immediate window or hovering over the variables to observe the values during your loop. You could also use Console.WriteLine() in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n < i)
```

`n` never changes its value within the loop, so with `n = 0`, this will end up with an infinite loop where `n` (which is `0`) is being added to `a`.

That being said, the amount of numbers between `1` and an arbitrary integer `n` (`n>1`) is `n - 1`. No need to loop anything.

Comment: I think he meant the sum of the numbers between 1 and n. Which of course has its own formula, but I would guess that the point of this exercise is to learn about flow control.

Comment: @Ryan Nothing in the questions suggests that this is the case though. And yes, it might be a very trivial problem but that does not mean that it is not in fact OP’s problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have constructed the while loop is not correct. Since `n = 0` and therefore `0` will be always less than the entered number, the statement `n < i` will be always true (I am assuming that `i > 0` will be entered)  and the `while` loop will never end, it will be infinite. You need to increment `n` so that at some point `n > i` and the loop will exit. See more about while loop here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/while

Do you want to count how many numbers are there between 1 and the number entered or you want to add all the numbers between 1 and the number entered?

In case of just counting, you can write:

```
static void AmountOfNumbers (ref int i,ref int n,ref int a)
{
   while (n < i)
   {
      a++;
      n++;
   }
}
```

In case you want the sum:

```
static void AmountOfNumbers (ref int i,ref int n,ref int a)
{
   while (n < i)
   {
      a += n;
      n++;
   }
}
```

Comment: This will create a sum of all the numbers though.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
while (n < i)
            {
                a += n;
            }
```

if any number > 0 is entered, this condition would always be true as you are no where modifying value of n. It should be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A function is usually a method which returns a value, so you might be looking for something more like

```
static int SumToN(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
        // uses the formula for the sum of numners 1..n
        return n * (n + 1) / 2;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    i = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    sum = SumToN(i);
    Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
    Console.Read();
}
```

You might also want to check the input value is <=65535 otherwise an overflow will occur in calculating the sum.